# Charts intercept touch events and prevent scrolling in c3 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I have a page fill with c3 js chart when i scroll a page in touch devices it wont scroll. how to prevent this?

It can't base64 value while using html2canvas.

Comment: I don't have the answer for you, but the issue has been raised on the [github page](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/798)

Comment: So it have no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is mentioned in the [github issue page](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/798#issuecomment-67310392) I shared with you:

[*aendrew* mentions to comment out the lines (233 - 238) in `interaction.js`](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/798#issuecomment-67310392)

```
// comment / remove these lines
.call(
        d3.behavior.drag().origin(Object)
            .on('drag', function () { $$.drag(d3.mouse(this)); })
            .on('dragstart', function () { $$.dragstart(d3.mouse(this)); })
            .on('dragend', function () { $$.dragend(); })
    );
```

After making those changes you'd have to use `grunt` to build the new javascript files which you could use in your project.